# How to make an end of file output it's data?

Tags: c++, function, output, eof

this is my first time asking a question so forgive me if I stumble over anything. I have been working on a project for a suspension system for a car. I needed to make 4 functions for the displacement of the car and tire and the velocity of the car and tire. I feel that I structured the code well but it's simply not outputting the final product. The main purpose is to find the maximum of each function. I tried a lot to try and fix it but I can't seem to come up with a solution. 
The main point is. I structured a program with four functions which the data file feeds with the information til it ends. When I try to run it nothing but the header is outputted. I am at a lost to how this is.

The data file has four groups ranging from car A to car D organized like so,
Spring Constant of tire, damp constant of dash-pot, mass of wheel, mass of car, start/end times, increment value

The functions themselves are sort of...Hard to swallow. So I would like to share some sections of code where I believe  problems are.

Any help/hints/comments would be most appreciated.

```
csdatafiles>> total_readings;      

csdatafiles >> car_name >> spring_constant_tire >> spring_constant_spring 
>> damp_constant >> mass_of_tire >> mass_of_car 
>> start_time_value >> end_time_value >> increment_time_value;



//Initialize max min
max_displacement_car=displacement_of_car;
max_displacement_tire=displacement_of_tire;
max_velocity_car=velocity_of_car;
max_velocity_tire=velocity_of_tire;


//Output Header
 cout << "\nCar Name    Max Tire Displace   Max Tire Vel   Max Car Displace   Max Car Vel \n" << endl;


{




//recall functions
velocity_of_tire= old_new_tire_velocity (variables needed);
velocity_of_car=old_new_car_velocity (variables needed);
displacement_of_car= old_new_car_displacement (variables needed);


//check for max
if (displacement_of_car>max_displacement_car)
    max_displacement_car=displacement_of_car;

if (displacement_of_tire>max_displacement_tire)
    max_displacement_tire=displacement_of_car;

if (velocity_of_car>max_velocity_car)
    max_velocity_car=velocity_of_car;

if (velocity_of_tire>max_velocity_tire)
    max_velocity_tire=velocity_of_tire;

total_readings++;

//read rest of data
csdatafiles >> spring_constant_tire >> spring_constant_spring 
>> damp_constant >> mass_of_tire >> mass_of_car 
>> start_time_value >> end_time_value >> increment_time_value;

} while (!csdatafiles.eof());
//Output
cout << car_name << max_displacement_tire << max_velocity_tire << max_displacement_car << max_velocity_car;
```

Comment: Start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every stage, and *never add to code that doesn't work.* You should start with a function that reads the data file and spits it out one field at a time, then build up from there.

Comment: Probably not the main problem, but one of the max-statements sets the tire displacement to the car's displacement `max_displacement_tire=displacement_of_car;`

Answer (score 1):

Just going off of the code that you posted, it looks like you tried to put a `do-while` but forgot the `do` ...

Instead of

```
do {

//recall functions
//...
//check for max
//...
//read rest of data
//....

} while (!csdatafiles.eof());
```

You have

```
{

//recall functions
//...
//check for max
//...
//read rest of data
//....

} while (!csdatafiles.eof());
```

which is **VERY** different! Without the `do`, your code is equivalent to:

```
{

//recall functions
//...
//check for max
//...
//read rest of data
//....

}

while (!csdatafiles.eof()) {
  ;
}
```

As you can see, there is an infinite loop **just before** the last cout statement, so you never reach it.

Comment: Thank you everybody that gave me some pointers. I'll make sure to always remember them.

Maditya, 
While slightly embarrassed that I overlooked a simple matter I did what you asked. Still gives me a blank output though. But by making a few cout << "TEST" << endl; statements across the do/while and it seems that the problem is the loop isn't getting past my function recalls. 

Any particular reason that would be? No matter where I put the function recall in the loop it always stops dead once it gets to it.

Comment: Without actually seeing the code for those functions, I can only guess maybe one of them has an infinite loop in it. Could you post the code for those functions? Also, put couts **between** the recall functions so we know which one we're getting stuck on.

Comment: You are literally a genius. There is a for statement to manipulate the time variable. (It really only effects the road_surface variable and that only effects tire velocity so at the beginning I had it in with the old_new_tire_velocity function) I moved it down by the other functions.

I figure the bulk of the code would be hard to read if I just put it here on this imgur link. [link](http://i.imgur.com/ybzqZ3a.jpg) I apologize for the lines of ///, it just seems easier to read if I make the code block like.

Comment: Wait so did you find the error or does it work? In the code you posted in the imgur link, the termination condition on your very first for-loop (which is in the definition of `old_new_tire_velocity`) is wrong - it's assigning (`time=end_time_value`) instead of checking equality (`time<=end_time_value`).

Comment: Also, what cout statements are showing up? If it's just `TEST TEST TEST1` then the problem is obviously in `old_new_tire_velocity`. I forgot to finish my previous comment but the assignment itself evaluates to true since presumably `end_time_value` is non-zero. So your for loop runs forever. :)

Comment: This poses as a problem. For each test the end times are different so I was hoping the information fed from the data file will assign it to the end_time for each test. I was able to get an output of
TEST TEST TEST1
TEST TEST TEST2
TEST TEST TEST3
TEST TEST TEST4
TEST TEST TEST5
TEST TEST TEST6
TEST TEST TEST7
TEST TEST8

So now it can run throughout the entire loop it just doesn't do anything useful. I'll tinker with it some more. Thank you for all your help so far!